# could anyone explain what instance attribute is in the ModelForm? [Django]

Tags: python, django, django-forms, instance

I need to know why may I need to use instance into ModelForm I read about it in Django document what I understand that it can replace with save() method somehow if that is correct why I have to use it if not how can I use it and why?

Comment: You will have to be more specific and provide links and examples. It is very hard to decipher what you are asking without more details and clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a record in your models whose pk=1. So first you fetch the instance, and then you can create a form in your views by passing the instance argument. So if changes are made to some fields, the same record will be updated.
In your views -

```
a = ModelName.objects.get(pk=1) //Fetching the record you want to update
form = ModelFormName((request.POST, instance=a) or None)
if form.is_valid():
    record = form.save(commit=False)
    //Modify the records fields which you get from form
    record.save()
// if not valid send it to template via context
```

Use this form in your templates as you would do in a normal form.